# What's the chance for a dart to fall on a given line?

Tags: probability, geometry

The Wikipedia article for "almost surely" gives this example.

> Suppose you throw a dart at a unit square. There is nothing else in the universe but you, the dart and the square - thus the dart must hit the square.
>   The dart will *almost never* hit a point on the diagonal of the square, because the diagonal has no area; however, there are points that are located on the diagonal, thus the chance of the dart hitting the diagonal is non-zero.

The last passage made me curious. What's the chance for the dart to hit a point on the diagonal of the square? It surely isn't 0, because there are points that belong to the diagonal, but it appears to be 0 because a diagonal doesn't have any area.

My thoughts so far were something similar to:

> A line has $\mathfrak c$ points (because it is comparable to the interval $[0;\sqrt{2}]$, which has cardinality $\mathfrak c$);
>   A square has ${\mathfrak c}^2$ points (because it is comparable to the interval $[(0,0);(1,1)]$, which has cardinality $\mathfrak c$);
>   Therefore the chance of hitting a point on the diagonal is $\frac{\mathfrak c}{\mathfrak c}$.

[Edit: what you might see as C is actually $\mathfrak c$ (`\mathfrak c`), the symbol for the cardinality of the continuum ($\mathfrak c = |\mathbb R|$).]
[Edit #2: Suppose **the dart lands in a point**, not in an area.]

Comment: In real life the dart has a physical size. There are delicate issues of measure involved in this question.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks for noticing, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

I couldn't believe that Wikipedia is uttering the sentence "thus the chance of the dart hitting the diagonal is non-zero"; and upon inspection it turned out that such a sentence is not there.

It is *possible* that the dart hits a point on the diagonal, and it is also *conceivable*  that it lands exactly on the point with coordinates $\bigl({1\over e},{1\over\pi}\bigr)$. But as soon as you try to weigh this possibility by some number $p\geq0$ which you then would call the *chance* or *probability*  of such an event you would quickly realize that the only value for $p$ that leads to coherent consequences is $p=0$.